# caption of a table

Tags: tables

I've got the following code:

```
\begin{center}
\sffamily
\captionof{table}{Codexample}
\begin{tabular}{ll}
\topule[2.5pt]
exampleline & example \\
...
\bottomrule[2.5pt]
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
```

I've added the `\captionof{table}{..}` in order to give my table a heading. I assume that the whole table is a floating object (I hope this is the right English expression) and LaTex decides more or less where to put it.

My problem is: In my document I've got some text before the table. LaTex produces an ugly PDF document: *The title of the table is on one page and the table itself on the next page.* How to correct that?

Comment: Use `\begin{table}\centering` and `\end{table}` instead of `center`; change `\captionof{table}` into `\caption`.

Answer (score 6):

Simply use

```
\begin{table}
\caption{Codexample}
\begin{tabular}{ll}
\toprule
exampleline & example \\
...
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

The table will float and be placed at a convenient position. You can also say

```
\begin{table}[htp]
```

so that LaTeX will try placing the table at the spot. See

- [How to influence the position of float environments like figure and table in LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/39017)
- [Keeping tables/figures close to where they are mentioned](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/2275)

for more information about floats.

As an aside, `\toprule[2.5pt]` will produce too thick a rule.